# Clarifying the "shopping question" close reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Our custom close reason for shopping questions is confusing.

It currently reads:

> Questions seeking **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because [they tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

This has two problems:

1. That they tend to become obsolete quickly is not the primary reason we close shopping questions. The primary reason is that [they attract low quality, opinionated, and spam answers](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6139/126632).
2. Asking users to describe their specific problem in this way isn't very helpful, since the user is almost always already trying to solve a problem, and usually has described it to some extent in their question.

How should this be reworded to address these issues? Remember that the goal here is to encourage higher-quality questions.

I've made my own suggestion below and I'm interested in hearing any other ideas.

Comment: I think this: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6112/proposal-sf-needs-its-own-shopping-link should be revisited as a possible new link in the "obsolete" URL of the close reason.  If you'd like I can try and write something up with pics, etc. like the normal shopping link but more ServerFault centric.

Comment: If we _had_ one then I'd certainly look at it!

Comment: Here you go Michael: http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6488/7861

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My suggested rewrite of this is:

> Requests for **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because they attract [low quality, opinionated and spam answers](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6140), and [the answers become obsolete quickly](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6488). Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: I like the text better, but now it doesn't match the linked article at all... though I think the problem is more with needing a better article to link.

Comment: Good point. When I find one, I'll link to it. If nothing better comes along I'll just link to [the meta Q&A I linked to in the question](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6139/126632). Ideally, I'd like to have a meta Q&A that explains how to ask this sort of question correctly, such as [the one on SU](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/144961).

Comment: The answer you linked to @TheCleaner is a much better explanation.  I think it should be linked in the close reason (slightly edited and posted elsewhere, perhaps).

Comment: @HopelessN00b It's the same post. I just linked to the answer there, and the question here. Easy enough to change.

Comment: Better, probably have to be good enough. Maybe reword slightly to "are off-topic because the answers they attract are low quality, opinionated, spam, or [become obsolete quickly](http://lazylink)", just to shorten it up a bit.

Comment: The problem with this text is that it doesn't clarify what sort of question is still permissible to ask. Falcon Momot's suggestion fixes that.

Answer (score 4):

I think maybe it should read:

> Requests for **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because they attract self-promotion and opinion-based answers, and [the answers become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  Instead, try asking how to solve the specific problem you are having, and describe your thinking on it so far.