# Can I ask for a comparison between two specific testing tools?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

I have a question about feature differences between two Fluke cable and network testing tools.

It's probably more appropriate for e.g. an Amazon community question but I havent been getting responses there.

Is it ok to ask it here, or is there any way I can formulate it to be appropriate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a question would most likely be considered a request for a product recommendation and closed as off-topic:

> **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com because they attract [low quality, opinionated and spam answers](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6140) and [the answers become obsolete quickly](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6488). Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

We expect a professional to be able to find the [product specs](http://www.flukenetworks.com/content/datasheet-linkrunner) and a feature comparison is also an exercise in "spot the differences" that doesn't take a rocket scientist and would make a low quality question.

[image: spot the differences]

In general we prefer questions that show that you already did some background research and which allow objective answers and a much better style of question would be:

> **What to look for in cable tester?**
>   My current tester is a $10,- unit that is only useful to determine a if a pair in patch cable is broken or not. 
>   I have seen testers that cost an arm and a leg but I don't really know what features are gimmicks and what should I really care about?
>    -  Do I really want to know the impedance and cross-talk numbers?
>    -  How useful and reliable is a distance measurement to a cable fault?
>    - Should I only care how much bandwidth a cable can support?
>    - Some tools specifically mention IPv6 support, what has IPv4 vs IPv6 to do with cable testing?
>   ...

Comment: That's what I thought. I threw the question out [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28054173#28054173) instead. Also I'll just call Fluke.

Comment: As you might have noticed the chatroom is pretty much dead. Calling a sales rep might be your best bet.

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing your actual question it is difficult to tell but my feeling is that it won't go down well.

Why can't you call/email Fluke and ask one of their sales engineers?

Comment: They've been nonresponsive to emails for a week. I'll just call them. I guess I've become too accustomed to not actually having to talk to people.

Comment: "I guess I've become too accustomed to not actually having to talk to people" I feel like that should be a t-shirt. Specifically, I feel like that should be **my** t-shirt.